# Vue 3 two-way binding Composition API with Firestore documents field

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, two-way-binding

**Edit:** I need to figure out how to get data from the document object inside the setup() function. Problem is that the document object is async.

I am new to Vue and is currently stuggeling with a two-way data binding.

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" v-model="title" class="form-
```

```js
    <script>
        import getDocument from 'getDocument'
        import { ref } from 'vue'
    
        export default {
            props: ['id'],
            setup(props) {
                const { error, document } = getDocument('items', props.id)
    
                const title = ref('')
    
                return { title }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I need to somehow set the `title.value = document.title`.

But `document.title` returns as `undefined`

`document` is an object from firestore here is the file:

```js
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const getDocument = (collection, id) => {

    const document = ref(null)
    const error = ref(null)

    // register the firestore collection reference
    let documentRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

    const unsub = documentRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
            if (doc.data()) {
                document.value = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
                error.value = null
            } else {
                error.value = 'That document does not exist'
            }
        }, err => {
            console.log(err.message)
            error.value = 'could not fetch the document'
        })

        watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
            onInvalidate(() => unsub());
        });

        return { error, document }
    }
}

export default getDocument
```

Comment: `document` is a ref, so it should likely be `document.value.title`, and `title` should likely be a computed that uses it.

Comment: You can also use [Suspense](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/suspense.html#introduction) and implement an `async setup()` function.